# how to make a custom error for empty input in a field (i.e. name = serializers.CharField(required=True))?

Tags: python, django

`name = serializers.CharField(required=True)`

```
def validate(self,data):
    if not name:
         //Return error
```

I want to validate name or check if it's empty in

`def validate_name(self,value):`

I tried to trigger def validate and def validate_name and I expected a return from there but
instead I am getting error from default rest framework

Comment: Add the error, please.

Comment: @Tarquinius I am not facing any error . What I am asking is that how will I be able to trigger def validate_name for an empty input.

Comment: Ok, I see. I have to say your phrasing "I am getting error from default rest framework" was a bit misleading though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in [Field-level validation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation) you'll see a note that states:

> Note: If your <field_name> is declared on your serializer with the
> parameter required=False then this validation step will not take place
> if the field is not included.

Knowing that, you'd want to change your code to `name = serializers.CharField(required=False)`. Bear in mind that the checking for a not empty value fully relies on your validation function.

If you want to customize the error for the empty input, you can use `serializers.ValidationError` class.

```
def validate_name(self, value):
        if not value.strip():  
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Name cannot be empty.")   #any custom error message                      
        return value
```

- Using `strip()` it checks that the value is empty or not.
- If the name is empty it raises the custom error msg with `serializers.ValidationError`.

Comment: I am not able to invoke the def validate_name when I send a empty input from postman .

Comment: @Sujar Hada, please check this updated version. Let me know if this now works for you.